# Com a saída do ViewScoped da nova especificação do JSF, qual escopo utilizar agora em meus beans gerenciados que o utilizavam usando JSF 2.2?

Tags: java, jsf, cdi, jee, jsf-2.2

Tenho uma grande dúvida agora com a aparição do JSF 2.2: O que fazer com minhas views e meus managed beans antigos? Como fazer agora (qual escopo utilizar) já que não posso usar mais view scoped numa view que precisa manter alguns objetos na memória entre requisições ajax?

Comment: Porque as tags [ejb] e [ejb3]? Esta questão não tem nada a ver com EJB.

Comment: Tags alteradas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Conforme : http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-22/#1087

La fala que a anotação @ViewScoped no pacote javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped deve se tornar deprecated, visto a criação da anotação @ViewScoped do pacote javax.faces.view.ViewScoped.

Acontece isso, visto a adoção de uma extensão do CDI, utilizando a segunda anotação. Caso não use o CDI, essa anotação não vai ter resultado algum.

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento, eu estava confundindo e pensando que a classe javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped era a que ia ficar...

Comment: E no caso de @SessionScoped, qual tag continuar usando?

Answer (score 3):

Voce pode e deve usar o ViewScoped do CDI: javax.faces.view.ViewScoped, porém claro, é necessario usar CDI beans.

O que ocorre é que a ViewScoped do JSF não funciona com beans CDI, e o JSF esta tomando o rumo em que os CDI beans substituirão os JSF Managed Beans. Sendo assim estão tomando as providencias para que futuramente todo o pacote javax.faces.bean se torne deprecated.

Mais informações aqui neste link: http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-22/#1087

Comment: Isso significa que por exemplo, uma aplicação web normal rodando em um servlet container como o tomcat daria suporte ao contexto de injeção de dependência?

Comment: Não é preciso um servidor de aplicações para usar CDI, pode ser um webcontainer como o tomcat mesmo.

Comment: Bem @Fred, andei dando uma pesquisada mais profunda e pelo meu entender um servlet container para fornecer os recursos de CDI precisa usar uma implementação do CDI, como exemplo o WELD, sendo que esta implementação abrangerá apenas Servlets 3.0 e não JSF...